# Edit page with "this site/list hasn't been shared with you" message

Tags: edit

Due to a migration I suspect a lot of users running into this message. Therefore I'd like to be able to immediately redirect them to the new location.

I suppose this is a 404 type page that should be editable?

Thnx!

Answer (score 0):

The error: **Sorry, this site hasn't been shared with you** is not that uncommon for first time SharePoint 2013 users. It simply means that you have not been granted access to the site. This error is cause by permissions/credentials access problem.

This is not 404 rather it is ** 403 access denied** error. You can use custom access denied page. check these

http://a2zdinesh.blogspot.in/2014/05/configure-custom-access-denied-page-bug.html

http://blog.randomdust.com/2013/07/custom-access-denied-page-in-sharepoint-2013/